# Seeds of fruits

Tags: fruit, seeds

Some fruits  ( like watermelon , pomegranate,  etc ) have their seeds spread out throughout their bulk . Also , there are fruits which have seeds at their centre of symmetry ( like apples ) .

*Is there any theory or mechanism which explains that why and which type of fruits possesses the type of arrangements of seeds inside their bulk ?*

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. This is not simply an answer site, but instead a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help. Consequently, **questions that show little or no prior research effort** are off-topic on this site as are ["homework"](https://biology.stackexchange.com/help/homework) questions **unless you have shown your attempt at an answer**. Please [edit] your question and tell us where you've looked for answers, what you *do* know about the topic, and where exactly you still have questions. Please take the [tour] and consult the [help] starting with [ask] for details.

Comment: In addition, biology is rarely (at least at this stage of knowledge) a matter of distilling rules — to make this an answerable question (for this site) I think you should focus on a single type of [fruit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit) and start by figuring out the botanical name for that type (e.g. [pome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pome)). You can then use search terms like "development fruit pome" to learn more and then ask a clear, focused question based on what you've learned if and when you get stuck.

Comment: I looked up and worked on it by asking to my teachers . They told that this may be due to weather , climate and geographical factors.

Comment: Sorry I missed your reply — your teachers's answers don't really seem at all helpful to me. Please note that asking good questions is a skill that one needs to work at. If you lack the time for or interest in improving this question (see previous comments for details), please delete it. This will prevent you from losing reputation (and can lead to loss of the privilege of asking questions) due to downvotes and closure.

Comment: @tyersome Hello , what I want was an answer not reputation. However , don't close it please.

Comment: Ultimately the decision of whether to close is up to the community. If you improve the question then it will be left open and is more likely to receive an answer ...

Comment: @tyersome Then please suggest me that how can I improve . What shall I omit and add to my question to improve it?

Comment: I already did that in my first two comments ...